# Genymotion Error : QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break

Tags: genymotion

Hi I have installed the Genymotion. I can sign to my account but when I want to add virtual device it crashes.

This the log :

```
Apr 14 16:39:54 [Genymotion] [debug] [WalkTemporaryDirectory] Path of search: "/home/rasoul/.Genymobile"
Apr 14 16:39:54 [Genymotion] [debug] [WalkTemporaryDirectory] Path of search: "/home/rasoul/.Genymobile/Genymotion/cache/network/"
Apr 14 16:39:54 [Genymotion] [debug] [WalkTemporaryDirectory] Path of search: "/home/rasoul/.Genymobile/Genymotion/templates/"
Apr 14 16:39:54 [Genymotion] [debug] [ComputeCacheSize] 105 bytes found
Apr 14 16:39:57 [Genymotion] [debug] Virtual devices directory: "/home/rasoul/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/"
Apr 14 16:39:57 [Genymotion] [debug] Screencast directory: "/home/rasoul"
Apr 14 16:39:59 [Genymotion] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/getall" ) 
Apr 14 16:39:59 [Genymotion] [debug] Genymotion template count: 107
Apr 14 16:39:59 [Genymotion] [debug] template list retrieved:  107
Apr 14 16:40:05 [Genymotion] [debug] Searching virtual device with same name
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Launching download
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/vmtemplate/2bb3d2b7-3b56-476a-b13e-ffc57722b1a5/getova" ) 
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Start timer
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Remote file size: 155371520 , current local file size: 0
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Starting new download
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Downloading file  "http://dl.genymotion.com/dists/4.1.1/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_4.1.1_170321_000946.ova"
Apr 14 16:40:08 [Genymotion] [debug] Start timer
Apr 14 16:40:10 [Genymotion] [fatal] QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Size mismatch for type 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry' [1024]. Previously registered size 16, now registering size 0.
```

Specific error is as the following:

```
QMetaType::registerType: Binary compatibility break -- Size mismatch for type 'QPaintBufferCacheEntry' [1024]. Previously registered size 16, now registering size 0.`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is described [here](https://blog.houseofus.eu/workaround-for-genymotion-qpaintbuffercacheentry/).

**In short**: copy the name of the `.ova` file from `~/.Genymobile/genymotion.log`, download it to `~/.Genymobile/Genymotion/ova`, then try to add the same device one more time.